# Existence of a UMP test for two binomial random variables

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, distributed as Binomial($p, n$) and Binomial($p^2, m$), respectively.  Does a [UMP test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) (for fixed level $\alpha$) exist for:  $H_0: p \leq p_0 \text{ vs. } H_1: p > p_0$?

In order to invoke the Karlin-Rubin theorem the monotone likelihood property is required, but it's not clear to me if we have that.

Comment: I don't see how MLR is going to applied here since the minimal sufficient statistic is $(X, Y)$.